# Swap tokens of a file name using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have file(s) in a folder with names like "223.DAT_2017010211315" I want to loop through all the files and rename them to like 223_2017010211315.DAT"

The closest I got to this requirement is as follows. I could just get the first token of the file name.

```
set "res=223.DAT_2017010211315"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%i in ("%res%") do (set prefix=%%i)
echo %prefix%
pause
```

Could someone help me through this?

Comment: Thank you every one for your prompt response.. I am able to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
REM for every file matching the filter do:
for %%f in (*.dat_*) do (
  REM disassemble into tree tokens, using . and _ as delimiters:
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=._" %%a in ("%%~f") do (
    REM re-assemble in different order:
    echo %%a_%%c.%%b
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by iterating the file system. This should search the required files and show them

```dos
for %%f in ("*.dat_*") do echo %%f
```

Now, once we are able to find the files to process we need to separate the name and the extension of the files. That is an easy task as the `for` replaceable parameters (`%%f` in previous code) allow the usage of some modifiers to retrieve specific information of the referenced file (see `for /?` for a full list). We will use `%%~nf` (the name of the file referenced by `%%f`) and `%%~xf` (the extension of the file being referenced by `%%f`)

```dos
for %%f in ("*.dat_*") do echo %%~nf   %%~xf
```

Once we have the two elements, we need to split the extension using the underscore as a delimiter. This will give us two tokens, left and right sides of the underscore. For this `for /f` is used to process the file extension.

```dos
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~xf") do echo %%a %%b
```

As we are requesting two tokens, the `for /f` will use the requested replaceable parameter `%%a` to store the first one, and will create an additional replaceable parameter `%%b` (next character) to store the second token.

```
%%~nf %%~xf
  [.][................]
  223.DAT_2017010211315  = %%f
     ^..^ ^...........^
     %%a  %%b
```

So, for each file in the list, execute the `for /f` to retrieve the needed information to execute the `ren` command.

```dos
for %%f in ("*.dat_*") do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~xf") do (
    echo ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%%b%%a"
)
```

Note that for debugging purpouses, the `ren` command is not executed, only echoed to console to check the code behaviour. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` and run the code again.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Just to show an alternative way:

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "X:\path\to\folder"
for %%A in (*.dat_*) do (
  set fname=%%A
  Echo ren "%%A" "!fname:.DAT=!.DAT"
) 
Popd
```

If output looks ok, remove the echo